# Typo3 - Use FlexForm value for DataQueryProcessor in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, flexform

I have a content element that stores values in a FlexForm (eg. 1234). The value represents an UID of a database table.

**What i want to do**:

- Get the single value which is stored in the FlexForm (Already working)
- Run a database query with this value
- Show the data in the frontend

**Problem**:
I don't know how to hand over the FlexForm value to the where-clause of the DB query.

```
tt_content {
  my_addresscontainer =< lib.contentElement
  my_addresscontainer {

    templateName = AddressContainer
    templateRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:xyz/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:xyz/Resources/Private/Partials
    }

    dataProcessing {
        1 = xyz\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
        1 {
            options {
                if.isTrue.field = pi_flexform
                fieldName = pi_flexform
            }
            as = content
        }

        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
               10 {
                  table = tt_address
                  pidInList = 19
                  markers {
                        myuid.value = 191901 <- This should be handed over...
                  }
                  where = uid =###myuid###
                  as = address_record
                }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to access the flexform value from your plugin/content element you can do that without a custom FlexFormProcessor. Use the data type `flexform`, e.g. like this:

```
dataProcessing {
  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
  10 {
    table = tt_address
    pidInList = 19
    uidInList.data = flexform:pi_flexform:settings.myuid
  }
}
```

You need to adjust `settings.myuid` according to the naming in your flexform. See the TypoScript Reference for details on the [data type `flexform`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/DataTypes/Index.html#flexform).

If you need your custom FlexFormProcessor, you need to nest the dataProcessing, something like this:

```
dataProcessing {
  1 = xyz\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
  1 {
    options {
      if.isTrue.field = pi_flexform
      fieldName = pi_flexform
    }
    as = content

    dataProcessing {
      1 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
      1 {
        table = tt_address
        pidInList = 19
        markers {
              myuid.value = 191901 <- This should be handed over...
        }
        where.wrap = uid =|
        as = address_record
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The important line is the `where.wrap` where you use the value from the first dataProcessing.